# Aws acm api access to issue certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-acm, aws-acm-certificate

I have an application with which I want to request new ACM certificate for a domain name. I want to do DNS validation for ACM to issue the cert.

I could not find reference to an API where ACM can respond with the DNS records need to be setup before issuing certificates.

How can I get the DNS records through API?

Answer (score 0):

DNS records are available in the describeCertificate API.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeCertificate.html